# Image is not being displayed from varbinary

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a SQL Server database and in one of the columns in my table is of type `varbinary(max)` and has a value like this:

```
0x3131313131313031313131313130313...
```

I couldn't enter the whole value because stackoverflow won't allow it.

I am fetching this data using api in my controller.

I am trying to display this image in ASP.NET MVC using the following markup in my `.cshtml` file:

```
<img alt="image" src="data:image/jpg;base64, @Convert.ToBase64String(item.FlImage)" height="200" width="200" />
```

but the image is not being displayed when I run it.

Can anyone help and explain what's going wrong?

Comment: try data:image/jpeg;base64, data:image/png;base64

Comment: i checked it image file extension is jfif.  i tried it using jpeg file also but still not working. what do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img alt="image" src="data:image/jpg;base64, @Convert.ToBase64String(item.FlImage)" height="200" width="200" />
```

this is the correct code. just make sure the extension of your image file and here in img tag match. plus my error was that my binary code was wrong in database. i fixed it and now its working.